# General help shortening a script from 279 chars to 259 chars MAX

Tags: powershell

I fully understand this is not exactly the intended purpose of this site and I may get some down votes, but if that comes with one persons help it is worth it

I wrote the following script that is meant to be executed from the run box.
Meaning it has to be 259 characters or less

This script will execute and then wait for a mouse movement

After one is detected it will open a youtube video

because they dont play automatically i have to use sendkeys to press the space bar

How can I shorten this by exactly 20 chars?

```
powershell -w h Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
$p=[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X;
while(1){if([Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X-ne$p){break}else{Sleep 3}};
start-process (short-youtube-url);sleep 3;
$o=New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$o.SendKeys(" ")
```

[image]

Comment: what run box? And why does it have the 259 character limit?

Comment: edited to include image of the runbox
and it has a 259 character limit

Comment: but why would you want to paste the command into it? If that's something that you use  again and again then you need to store it as a \*.ps1 file then just double click it to run

Comment: I make payloads for the hak5 devices. 
Funny little prank payloads that run on devices that mimick a keyboard. 
WIN+R opens run command 
type that out and ENTER
Basically a device that operates like SendKeys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
powershell -w h Add-Type -AssemblyName *m.W*s.F*s;
$w=[Windows.Forms.Cursor];
$p=$w::Position.X;
while(1){if($w::Position.X-ne$p){break}else{Sleep 3}};
saps (short-youtube-url);sleep 3;
$o=New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$o.SendKeys(" ")
```

- Replaced `-AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` with asterisks for wildcard matching
- Set `[Windows.Forms.Cursor]` into a variable
- Replaced `Start-Process` with alias `saps`

Comment: you are incredible 
it absolutely does 
i actually did the saps replacement and Set [Windows.Forms.Cursor] into a variable but had no idea about wild card matching, that is something I need to get proficient at
thank you a lot

Comment: You can further golf it like this: `Add-Type -As *m.W*s.F*s` and `New-Object -C WScript.Shell`, because all options in PowerShell can be called by their minimal unique string. You can also use option alias: `Add-Type -AN *m.W*s.F*s`